# Webjars not working on vert.x application

Tags: vert.x, webjars

What is the proper way to configure webjars in a vert.x application? I have this simple app:

```
class WebVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {

  override suspend fun start() {
    val router = Router.router(vertx)

    // Serve static resources from the /assets directory
    router.route("/").handler(StaticHandler.create())

    val json = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx).getConfigAwait()
    val port = json.getInteger("port")
    try {
      vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listenAwait(port)
      println("HTTP server started on port $port - redeploy enabled")
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
      error("Could not spawn web server at port $port")
    }
  }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    <version>${vertx.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>vue</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.16</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>vmp</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>package</goal>
            <goal>initialize</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <redeploy>true</redeploy>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

The file structure as following:

```
src/main/resources/webroot
| index.html
```

When I hit `localhost:8888` it does work but `localhost:8888/vue/vue.js` does not.
Is there something else that I need to configure?

Answer (score 1):

Change the router configuration to:

```
router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create("META-INF/resources"))
```

Then point your browser to:

```
http://localhost:8888/webjars/vue/2.5.16/vue.js
```

Comment: Still not managed to make it work, if you can, please, check the code at https://github.com/vitorvezani/investimentus/tree/master/backend

Comment: It [seems](https://github.com/vitorvezani/investimentus/blob/master/backend/src/main/kotlin/com/investimentus/backend/WebVerticle.kt#L18) you haven't changed the `StaticHandler` config